# Return to previous page while in folder in document library returns me to an empty page?

Tags: 2013, web-part, document-library, folder

I got a document library web part on a page, and it contains a folder, named X. When I click on folder X, it refreshes the page and now shows the contents of that folder, in which I can see folder Y.

When I open folder Y, once again the page refreshes and this time I see the contents of folder Y.

I placed a simple link on that page that should return the user to the previous page (the href is set with javascript to be the value of "document.referrer"). It does return to the URL of the previous page, **but the content of the page is always empty.**

Even stranger, when I am on a page with a document library web part that has a folder and I open that folder, and click on the URL in my browser window and press enter, the page also ends up with empty content. When I just refresh the page, this does not happen (even though refreshing it and pressing enter on the address should do the same).

*Why can't I see the contents of the page when I manually refresh the page, and when I decide to go back to the previous page using an anchor tag that uses the referrer?*

I really can't figure it out... Do you guys perhaps have an idea on what might cause this?

Comment: Having you tried using the <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</a> ?

Comment: Yes, and it has the same result. :(